# What would be the binary bit pattern in memory representing +66?

Tags: math, binary, bit-manipulation, cpu-architecture, twos-complement

I'm told that my answer to the following question is incorrect. Am I really incorrect? I don't see how.

Assume a 1-byte signed integer using two's complement representation and the most significant bit is the sign bit.  What would be the binary bit pattern in memory representing +66?

**The answer is 01000010**

Right?

Comment: i don't think you are wrong

Comment: is +66 decimal, octal or hexadecimal?

Comment: @mch when no suffix added then +66 means decadic base but yes you're right he might overlook/forget to write the base. The only other thing I can think of is  LSB (least significant bit) position (on the left or right)? if LSB is on the right then it is correct otherwise it need bit reversal

Comment: heh but on 8 bits the number is palindrome so it really does not matter

Comment: @Spektre IMO that's the only possibility where this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might be arguing with a pedant who has a detailed version of what "bit pattern in memory" means. This conversion to binary is correct, but they may want you to think about the relevance of word size, or endianness.

you could always lay out your proof:

66 / 2 = 33 R 0

33 / 2 = 16 R 1

16 / 2 = 8 R 0

8 / 2 = 4 R 0

4 / 2 = 2 R 0

2 / 2 = 1 R 0

1 / 2 = 0 R 1

(reading bottom to top) 1000010

(adding extra zero on left size to make a byte) 01000010

(sanity check) (1 * (2^6)) + (1 * (2^1)) = 64 + 2 == 66